# Device not Recognize AVD Device on Usb Debugging

Tags: android, driver, android-debug

My Company launches new Android study Tab manufactured by China's company . I am facing a problem for testing my app on this Tab.
I can upgrade Operating System of Tab using drivers. But I am unable to use device as a AVD.
I switched on the usb debugging from Developer's option.

Is there difference between drivers for upgrading operating system and using device as a AVD?

how can I use my device for Debugging?

OS- Jellybean 4.1, Windows 7.
thanks

Comment: r u using Windows or linux?

Comment: Go to Device Manager and see if the device driver for the Tab is installed properly.

Comment: I reinstall the driver manually. but it doesn't work.

Comment: A physical device is `not` an AVD (Android Virtual Device).

Comment: Is AVD devices are different???
If yes then Can I make my device as AVD??

Comment: my question is solved.
I get device drivers id and save it in .android /adb_usb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem is solved... 
I get device driver's Id from Device Manager.
 and put it in .android/adb_usb with 0x.
then Restart the computer.
 The link of images are- 
http://www.dropbox.com/s/3pa9ghno40lblhr/adb_usb.png 
http://www.dropbox.com/s/5fd23e4oqyldbfj/driver%20id.png

Answer (score 1):

It maybe due to adb driver for your phone is not properly installer.

I recommend you to use [Adb Driver Installer](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/).

It will detect any defected driver installed for your phone and then it will repair it automatically.

Comment: Try this command "adb devices" from command prompt and see if your device is listed there?

Comment: Only conclusion is that you don't have the correct adb driver for your phone remove all adb drivers you installed and try to get correct adb driver for you phone and then do a clean install.

Comment: But I can reinstall the Operating system on device wirh these drivers.
Is ADB drivers are different from the OS upgrading drivers???

Comment: Can you describe which tool and how you're upgrading the OS?
As I know if you are upgrading android from your pc then it requires ADB and FASTBOOT drivers.

Comment: my question is solved.
I get device drivers id and save it in .android /adb_usb.

Comment: Congratulation! If you can post the procedure to solve this problem as an answer then it will be helpful for others.

Comment: I get device driver's Id from Device Manager. and put it in .android/adb_usb with 0x.
then Restart the computer.
the link of images are- 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pa9ghno40lblhr/adb_usb.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5fd23e4oqyldbfj/driver%20id.png
You you solved it with your device then cote my question.

Comment: I mean post as answer on this question not as comment and then mark it as correct answer so anybody can find which is answer can solve their problem. (You can answer your own question and mark it as correct answer :))

Comment: I was unable to post as answer. 
but I m voted up.
I will post it as answer. 
thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem for a `Samsung` device.I installed the required `Samsung Kies` and `USB` drivers but still it doesn't show in the `AVD` chooser screen. So I downloaded a driver installer software.After installing that, it showed that a updated version of `Samsung Kies` is available then I updated it and everything worked fine.You can download that software from [here](http://www.driverupdate.net/)