# Eclipse cannot recognise my GT-N7000 device as AVD

Tags: java, android, eclipse, samsung-mobile

I have just migrated from Win 7 to Windows 8.1 to develop my Android project using Eclipse (Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)). When connect my Android device (SAMSUNG GT-N7000) on windows 8.1, it recognized by Windows and I can explore the folders of device.

But when run the Android project, Eclipse can not recognize this device and I receive below message:

> Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs'.

Comment: Did you open developer mode of your phone? If yes, try the correct answer steps: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503289/device-not-recognize-avd-device-on-usb-debugging)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're hoping that eclipse will run your program on the phone that is plugged into the computer, is that right? If so, why not create a virtual device instead using the Virtual device manager.